# Unable to form a single query to join multiple tables

Tags: java, sql, inner-join

I have to write a single select query to fetch all details from seven tables. Earlier I had separate queries but now I am working on optimizing the queries.
The following is my table structure :

```
Main Table (SN, model , regId) -- 1 row
Table1(col1,col2....SN)  - SN is forienKey  -- 1 row
Table2(col1,col2,....SN) -  SN is forienKey   -- 1 row
Table3(col1,col2,.....regId) - regId is forienKey  -- 1 row
Table4(col1,col2,.....regId) - regId is forienKey - 2 rows
Table5(col1,col2,.....regId) - regId is forienKey - 2 rows
Table6(col1,col2,.....regId) - regId is forienKey  - 1 row
```

There is a `one to many mapping` between the `main table` and `table 4` and `table 5`.

I have tried using inner join to fetch the rows but I am getting duplicate values. Below is the query that I have written. Is there anything I am missing?

```
select * from MainTable 
   inner join Table1 on MainTable.SN = Table1.SN
   inner join Table2 on MainTable.SN = Table2.SN
   inner join Table3 on MainTable.regId = TABLE3.regId
   inner join TABLE4 on MainTable.regId = Table4.regId
   inner join TABLE5 on MainTable.regId = Table5.regId
   inner join TABLE6 on MainTable.regId = Table6.regId
```

Comment: Why do you mix JOIN USING and WHERE clause join conditions? Very confusing.

Comment: There is a one to many relationship between tables, and you are asking us to make it a one to one relationship; How do you suppose we do that, we don't know your data. Which of the multiple rows do you want to show? Or do you want to aggregate the multiple rows?

Answer (score 0):

try joining tables like below to join all of them together

```
  select * from (select * from MainTable 
        inner join Table1 on MainTable.SN = Table1.SN
        inner join Table2 on Table1.SN = Table2.SN ) tempMain 
   inner join Table3 on tempMain.regId = TABLE3.regId
   inner join TABLE4 on TABLE3.regId = Table4.regId
   inner join TABLE5 on Table4.regId = Table5.regId
   inner join TABLE6 on Table5.regId = Table6.regId
```

though from your example i don't know if table2 & table 3 are related. anyways you can try to find similar.

Comment: table2 and table 3 has no relation

Comment: check edited answer may be.. inner sqls depend on database .. e.g Oracle you can use WITH query to build temp table & reuse it